# TypoScript: {field:uid} replacement not working | Different CSS class per menu item

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a header menu and try to define different CSS classes for each item.

This is what I have:

```
20 = HMENU
  20 {
    special = directory
    special.value = 107
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      wrap = <ul class="foo" id="mymenu">|</ul>
      expAll = 1
      NO = 1
      NO.allWrap = <li class="first menu_{field:uid}">|</li> || <li class="menu_{field:uid}">|</li> || <li class="last menu_{field:uid}">|</li>
    }
  }
```

But in the HTML output I simply get `class="first menu_{field:uid}"` and nothing is replaced.

By the way: The page entries in the menu are links to external pages.

EDIT:

As our designer complained about the non-speaking class IDs we are abusing the body-class attribute now:

```
  NO.allWrap = <li class="first {field:bodyclass_wrap_class}">|</li> || <li class="{field:bodyclass_wrap_class}">|</li> || <li class="last {field:bodyclass_wrap_class}">|</li>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add `NO.allWrap.insertData = 1`, then the data will be inserted. `allWrap` is just a normal `stdWrap`, so the [default features](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/stdWrap#insertData) apply there.

BTW: I think your [option split](http://wiki.typo3.org/De%3aTSref/optionSplit) is still wrong. I guess you want to have it like this:

```
NO.allWrap = <li class="first menu_{field:uid}">|</li> |*| <li class="menu_{field:uid}">|</li> |*| <li class="last menu_{field:uid}">|</li>
```

Comment: Stay away from `insertData = 1`!!! This is a security problem! Imagine somebody uses `{DB:be_user|0|password}` inside a page title. Then the password of the backend user will get printed in frontend. Instead use `dataWrap`. This will not replace values inside the page titles, because it does the `insertData` ***before*** the wrap. So just use `NO.stdWrap.dataWrap = ...`.

Comment: What do you mean with `somebody uses {DB:be_user|0|password} inside a page title`? The curly brackets are special chars and will be escaped. But even if not, only a backend user can edit the page properties, so why would someone hack his/her own TYPO3?

Comment: So all your backend users can read all of you configuration and all values inside all tables? The difference between `insertData = 1` and `dataWrap` is that `dataWrap` only replaces stuff for the content that is wrapped, but `insertData = 1` even replaces markers found inside that data that is wrapped. So if you wrap page titles and use `dataWrap = 1`, then all marker found in page titles are replaced. That can be useful, but mostly is not wanted. Of course it depends on your trust to your editors.

Comment: The security team recommends not to use `insertData` at all. So please fix your answer that fixes the problem, but introduces an unwanted security risk. Or do you really think he wants to replace `{...}` markers in page titles? He wants to replace the markers in the wrap. Actually I am thinking about flagging it for showing an exploit.

Comment: AFAIK this [has been fixed](http://buzz.typo3.org/teams/security/article/breaking-changes-in-the-latest-typo3-security-release/) in the core about one year ago.

Comment: Please read your link closely! It talks about one spot where exactly this mistake was done: Using `insertData` instead of `dataWrap`. What you are doing, is to introduce that very issue with your answer. I can not be fixed in core, because it is not a core bug, but a user configuration error.

Comment: Try it out, it will not work anymore! Cite from the post: "So we had to move the headline wrapping to the "dataWrap" property, which is a breaking change..."

Comment: You are right, but for the wrong reason. The code for `wrapItemAndSub` is very special and does not behave like a normal `stdWrap`. It renders the submenu, the `stdWrap` for `wrapItemAndSub` and then puts it all together with another wrap. That way `insertData = 1` has no influence to the content. This is not a security feature and especially not related to the security bulletin (which is about a Typoscript bug in CSS Styled Content and fixed with Typoscript only). Have a look at https://gist.github.com/3023546 to see that the problem is real. Do *not* teach users to use `insertData = 1`.

Comment: Btw, the code is unchanged since 2003 and commited by Kasper. Only Susanne did a cleanup in 2010 for stdWrap speed and Wolters did some CGL cleanup just recently. What I wrote about `wrapItemAndSub` is true for `allWrap` too, because the code uses the same strange logic.

Comment: @pgampe Can you add a more secure solution as a new answer?

Comment: This answer does not open up any security problem at all. Even if the stated example above would work (which it does not), the return value will be a salted md5 hash and not a plain text password. So even with a hash table, you won't be able to get back the plain text password. But even if that would apply, why would this guy need another backend password? He already has one, because editing the page title is not possible without... 

Anyway, the solution you are asking for is already in the comments above. You may use dataWrap instead of allWrap and then the insertData is no longer necessary.

Comment: The security problem is, that you can read all TYPO3 vars just as an normal editor. This includes @$TYPO3_CONF_VARS@, as well as any DB field (you just have to guess the right row). Eventually you might even be able to read @GP@ vars with it with could allow a nasty SQL injection, not to talk about XSS. I will not give you an example, but trust me - the problem is real.