# How can I style a menu item differently depending on FE group access to the linked page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Our client would like to have certain pages styled differently in a menu, depending on FE group access.

The idea is to give certain menu items, that are only visible to moderators, a little icon to make it clear to moderators that this page is only available to them.

I'm sure I could come up with a solution by implementing the logic in PHP, but I would prefer to solve this in pure TypoScript to make maintenance easier for future maintainers of the site.

I like the idea of [applying a style through CSS based on the UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141213/typoscript-fielduid-replacement-not-working-different-css-class-per-menu-i), but that seems like a maintenance hell in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `USR` state to apply a different wrap

```
10 = HMENU
10.1 = TMENU
10.1.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
10.NO = 1
10.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
10.ACT < .NO
10.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-active">|</li>
10.USR < .NO
10.USR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu-user">|</li>
```

There is not combination for user and active, thus I recommend another approch.

Modify the link depending on some page properties of the processed page:

```
10.NO.wrapItemAndSub.override = <li class="menu-user">|</li>
10.NO.wrapItemAndSub.override {
  # the list of matching fe groups
  if.value = 1,3
  if.isInList.field = fe_group
}
```

Also have a look at the power of `TypoScript` conditions. http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/5/#id553579

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to do:

1. Set `Usergroup Access Rights` for these pages only for selected groups (so they won't be visible to others)
2. Use [TS condition](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/4/) to modify CSS/JS or whatever else if required.

sample

```
[usergroup = 1,2]
lib.moderator_menu = HMENU
// ... etc
[end]
```

The easiest way for adding icon to menu item is using CSS:

```
<div id="main_menu">
  <a href="some-moderator-page.html" id="page_123" class="mod_link_icon">Moderators only</a>
</div>
```

and in css file:

```
#main_menu a {
    display:block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.mod_link_icon{
    padding-left:25px;
    background: url("img/moderator_icon1_20x20.png") no-repeat left top;
}
```

Tip: you can use also a jQuery [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)  to set required `mod_link_icon` class for the `#page_123` element for selected user groups.

```
<div id="main_menu">
  <a href="some-moderator-page.html" id="page_123">Moderators only</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // displays only when user's in 'moderator' group
    $('#page_123').addClass('mod_link_icon');
</script>
```

Comment: Step 1 is already completed. Step 2 is what I'm struggling with. The page tree in question contains pages with differing access restrictions (imagine 10 pages on the same level, 3 of those are moderator-only). So I won't be able to apply anything on a whole menu.

Comment: Well, yeah, I am aware of the capabilities of TS conditions. It's just not clear how you would apply them to do what I'm asking.

Comment: By adding ie. simple CSS class to the item, which will display an icon as a ... background of the A element. Check my edited answer.